# Melt & dcast w/ string concatenation

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

Suppose I have the following data.frame:

```
foo <- data.frame(CONTACT_DATE = c(rep(as.Date("2015-09-15"),3), rep(as.Date("2015-09-16"),3)), ISSUE = c("abc", "def", "xyz", "abc", "xyz", "def"), ISSUE_COUNT = c(1000,750,100,1500,200,100), RANK = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
> foo
  CONTACT_DATE ISSUE ISSUE_COUNT RANK
1   2015-09-15   abc        1000    1
2   2015-09-15   def         750    2
3   2015-09-15   xyz         100    3
4   2015-09-16   abc        1500    1
5   2015-09-16   xyz         200    2
6   2015-09-16   def         100    3
```

How do I go from the above to:

```
CONTACT_DATE ISSUE_RANK_1 ISSUE_RANK_2 ISSUE_RANK_3
2015-09-15   abc (1000)   def (750)    xyz (100)
2015-09-16   abc (1500)   xyz (200)    def (100)
```

I believe I have I have to use `melt` & `dcast` from `reshape2` but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo %>%
  mutate(ISSUE_COUNT = paste0("(", ISSUE_COUNT, ")"),
         RANK = paste0("ISSUE_RANK_", RANK)) %>%
  unite(VAR, ISSUE, ISSUE_COUNT, sep = " ") %>%
  spread(RANK, VAR)
```

Which gives:

```
#  CONTACT_DATE ISSUE_RANK_1 ISSUE_RANK_2 ISSUE_RANK_3
#1   2015-09-15   abc (1000)    def (750)    xyz (100)
#2   2015-09-16   abc (1500)    xyz (200)    def (100)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, `dcast` uses the last column of input table as the value in the output table.

```
library(reshape2)
d = read.table(text="id CONTACT_DATE ISSUE ISSUE_COUNT RANK
1   2015-09-15   abc        1000    1
2   2015-09-15   def         750    2
3   2015-09-15   xyz         100    3
4   2015-09-16   abc        1500    1
5   2015-09-16   xyz         200    2
6   2015-09-16   def         100    3", header=T)
d$x = paste(d$ISSUE, paste0("(",d$ISSUE_COUNT,")"))   # create new column with values that will appear in table
dcast(CONTACT_DATE ~ RANK, data=d)
```

Output:

```
  CONTACT_DATE          1         2         3
1   2015-09-15 abc (1000) def (750) xyz (100)
2   2015-09-16 abc (1500) xyz (200) def (100)
```

Comment: Why are you `read.table`-ing the OP's input? The very first line actually gives the input, `foo <- data.frame(...`